# How to use converting constructor to initialize vector

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `A` can be constructed from a `string` and thus defines a conversion from `string` to `A`.

```
class A
{
  public:

    A(std::string s) : s_(s) {}

  private:

    std::string s_;
};


class B
{
  public:

    B() : v_{"foo", "bar"} {}

  private:

    std::vector<A> v_;
};
```

Class `B` has a `vector` member containing `A` objects. The constructor initializes the vector (`v_`) with strings. This does not work. Why?

Comment: Please include the error message

Comment: I'd avoid using such implicit convertions inside my code. It can lead to unpredictable results. In your `B` constructor you even expect 2 implicit convertions at once: first it's `const char *` to `std::string` and then `std::string` to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your `std::vector<A>` expects to be constructed using an initializer list containing `A` objects. The compiler cannot implicitly convert an initializer list of `std::string` objects into one containing `A`s, and none of the other `std::vector` constructors take two `std::string`s (and even if one constructor did, it probably wouldn't have the meaning you're looking for).

If you write

```
B() : v_{A("foo"), A("bar")} {}
```

instead, it works.  Now you have an initializer list of `A`s, which gets interpreted correctly.

Comment: Or `v_{"foo"s, "bar"s}`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't do transitive conversions. See [the documentation here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast).

> **A user-defined conversion** consists of *zero or one non-explicit single-argument constructor* or non-explicit conversion function call

Emphasis mine. So when doing this

```
vector<A>{"str"}
```

you're actually requesting the conversion sequence

```
const char* --> std::string --> A
```

Since there's more than one conversion there, it can't compile. You need just one in order for it to work, and you can do it by issuing

```
vector<A>{A("str")}
```

Comment: Or `vector<A>{"str"s}`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Definitely, though no `c++11` tag :(

Comment: C++14, and we shall assume the current version of the language (which is now two years old) unless the question is tagged [tag:c++03]/[tag:c++11] for legacy problems.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, that approach seems to make more sense. Adopted.